Why is the cursor in a TextField jumping to the beginning of the text whenever the onChanged event is triggered?
My app has (among other things) a TextField and ElevatedButton. I'm managing state with Provider. I want the button color to change from white to blue when the TextField's content changes.
I have this code in the TextField:
 onChanged: (_) {
   context.read<Data>().changeButtonColor();
   },

This in the ElevatedButton:
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
   backgroundColor: context.watch<Data>().buttonColor),

And this in the Provider:
Color buttonColor = Colors.white;
void changeButtonColor() {
  buttonColor = Colors.blue;
  notifyListeners();
}

The button's color changes as expected. The problem I have, however, is that the cursor in the TextField jumps to the beginning of the text as soon as the onChanged event is triggered. That makes the app unusable.
Why does the cursor do this? And how do I make the code work as desired, i.e., without the TextField cursor jumping to the beginning of the text?

EDIT: the parent build() method includes
Note? selNote = context.watch<Data>().selectedNote;
noteTextController.text = selNote.content;

For reference, here's the complete code for the two widgets:
// Note Text TextField---------------------------------
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 15,
                  bottom: 15,
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: noteTextController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: null,
                  minLines: 10,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onChanged: (_) {
                    context.read<Data>().changeButtonColor();
                  },
                ),
              ),

 // Save Button------------------------------------------
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 15,
                  bottom: 15,
                ),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: context.watch<Data>().buttonColor),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    selNote = context.read<Data>().selectedNote;

                    var title = noteTitleController.text;
                    var content = noteTextController.text;
                    // If this is a new note ... create it
                    if (selNote == null) {
                      context.read<Data>().add(title, content);
                    } else {
                      // If this is an already existing note ... update it
                      selNote!.title = title;
                      selNote!.content = content;
                      context.read<Data>().update(title: title, content: content);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Save'),
                ),
              ),


How do you define the controller? What does the parent widget look like? Also, can you try adding a key to the TextField?

@DhafinRayhan I edited question. The two Padding widgets above are children of a ListView, which is a child of a Container inside a ListView.

The problem is that you're changing the controller's text inside the build method. Every time your TextField calls the onChanged callback, the value of button color in the provider will be updated so when it's being watched in the same widget, it will retrigger the build method which causes the controller's text to be updated, hence the cursor jump.
A TextField's value should be local, and you shouldn't manually handle the text change if the source of the change is from the TextField itself. Just rely on the internal change from the controller, and if you want to "mirror" the state to a more global state, you can keep the onChanged callback. You don't need to read back the value to the controller.
More generally, you shouldn't call the controller.text setter in a declarative/reactive manner. It should only be called in an imperative manner.

Some related articles:

Differentiate between ephemeral state and app state
AVOID using providers for local widget state (this is from a different state management package, Riverpod, but still relatable)


First, thank you for your explanation. The first two paragraphs are vy helpful. If you have the time, could you expand a little on the last paragraph? I’m unsure what it means. I just know I’ve viewed things like Flutter’s Provider as a way to separate UI from business logic, and thought I needed to use Controllers to manipulate TextField text.

When you pass a TextEditingController to a TextField, it will handle updating the text stored by itself. Basically, having this controller inside a State of a StatefulWidget is already a state management thing.

PS I did read [this] (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/imperative-vs-declarative-programming-difference/) to help me understand generally.

In Flutter, there is "ephemeral state", which handles local widget state, and an "app state", which handles app-wide states. A TextEditingController should always be an ephemeral state. Whether you want the value to be exposed to an app state, it doesn't matter, the controller still has to handle the state by itself. You can then make a new app-wide state, and copy the controller's state to it, but don't make the controller to read back the value from the app state.

The code inside build should not have side effects, such as an imperative action just like how you tell the controller to update its value. It should be only used to render widget, and probably make some pure computation to get some computed values that need to be fed to the widgets. Imperative methods, on the other side, can have side effects, and examples for this are the onTap or onPressed callback of buttons and gesture detectors.

Also note that the Flutter framework can call the build method how many times it wants, and it's expected to call the build method up to 60-120 times per seconds, so that's why it has to be pure (but of course, due to optimizations, this does not usually happen).

Oh by the way, I added two links in the answer that might be related. Hope that helps!

Awesome. Appreciate the completeness of your response(s). Thank you!

PS For anyone seeing this message later, I didn't know when writing it that when you programmatically set the value of a text controller, assigning a value to its text property, the cursor will jump to the beginning of the text. This is the crux of the issue I was asking about.

PPS Another source of confusion, to me, related to the app wide vs ephemeral state thing. Because the text in the `TextField` is also displayed in other widgets, I think of it as app wide state.